# Number of ArcGIS server users for CAL-based back-ends?

Tags: arcgis-server, license, sql-server

The licenses for our organization's MS SQL and ArcGIS Server are such:

MS SQL: CAL
ArcGIS Server: enterprise

Are the number of users that can be served still limited to the number of CALs present in MS SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes running a SDE service for users to connect will consume cals. The best way to connect is with direct connect. ArcGIS help has guidance for this.

Comment: Cold you give me a link to the help you're specifying?